# C# WinForms DataGridView: drop down opened/closed event?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datagridviewcomboboxcolumn

Is there a chance to know when the dropdown list of a DataGridViewComboBoxColumn is opened (and closed), regardless of the eventual value change?

I'm asking because I'd like to stop the underlying DataSource from updating, while the dropdown list is open. The DataSource updates once every second, and I find rather annoying that, when I open the list of a combo, the focus inside it keeps on moving to the actual value when the DataSource refreshes, even when the mouse pointer is on another value.

Thank you!

Comment: Sounds like a possible XY issue - why are you updating the DS every second?  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: You can handle `EditingControlShowing` and get the `ComboBox` using `e.Control`. Then you can attach a handler to  its events. There are a lot of examples around, like [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33079142/3110834).

Comment: @Plutonix: the DataSource (a BindingList) updates every second in a task that polls values via serial port/tcp port requests. So I have a value column (textbox), the only one updated in that task, and then other columns (including comboboxes), representing settings that can affect the signal acquisition.

Comment: @RezaAghaei: thanks for the tip, but unfortunately it's not excactly what I needed, since that event triggers even when the combobox cells gets the focus (I have EditOnEnter as EditMode of the DataGridView). I'd need to know when the dropdown list is opened.

Comment: @Alberto The linked post is an example which shows how to handle events of the combo box, I'm not saying you should handle `ClickEvent`. You should first handle `EditingControlShowing`. Then get `ComboBox` using `e.Control`, then attach event handlers to `DropDown` and `DropDownClosed` events of the `ComboBox` to detect when it opens/closes.

Comment: @RezaAghaei you are completely right, works like a charm and sorry for not checking your first comment properly :(

Comment: No problem, you learned new things :)